# TextInput doesn't filter FlatList items

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, flatlist

I'm using Typescript, form some reason the function below gives me the error: `Property 'title' doesn't exist on type 'never'`. If i write the same function in JS it doesn't give me error, only in Typescript. I don't know why, but my TextInput doens't filter the FlatList items.

```
    const searchFilter =(text) => {
        if(text){
            const newData = masterData.filter((item) => {
                //the error appears in the next line below in 'item.title'
                const itemData = item.title ? item.title.toUpperCase() : ''.toUpperCase(); 
                const textData = text.toUpperCase();
                return itemData.indexOf(textData) > -1;
            });
            setFilteredData(newData);
            setSearch(text);
        } else {
            setFilteredData(masterData);
            setSearch(text);
        }
    }
```

My FlatList works and show the data from the JSON fetch. The only problem is when i start typing in the `TextInput` and the FlatList disappears.

Full code below:

```
const ManageCustomersScreen =(props: ManageCustomersScreen) =>{
    //navigation
    const backPage = () => props.navigation.navigate("Home");
    const callCustomer = () => props.navigation.navigate("Customer");

    const [filteredData, setFilteredData] = useState([]);
    const [masterData, setMasterData] = useState([]);
    const [search, setSearch] = useState('');

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchPosts();
        return() => {

        }
    }, [])
  
    const fetchPosts = () => {
        const apiUrl = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users';
        fetch(apiUrl)
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((responseJson) => {
            setFilteredData(responseJson);
            setMasterData(responseJson);
        }).catch((error) => {
            console.error(error);
        })
    }

    const ItemView = ({item}) => {
        return(
            <View style={manageCustomersStyle.tableBody}>
            <View style={manageCustomersStyle.customerCard}>
                <TouchableOpacity
                style={manageCustomersStyle.customerCardContent}
                onPress={callCustomer}>
                    <View style={manageCustomersStyle.customerCardInfo}>
                        <Text style={manageCustomersStyle.customerCardInfoName}>{item.name}</Text>
                        <Text style={manageCustomersStyle.customerCardInfoId}>{item.id}</Text>
                    </View>
                    <Icon
                        name="angle-double-right"
                        size={40}
                        color="grey"
                    />
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
        </View>
        )
    }

    const searchFilter =(text) => {
        if(text){
            const newData = masterData.filter((item) => {
                const itemData = item.title ? item.title.toUpperCase() : ''.toUpperCase();
                const textData = text.toUpperCase();
                return itemData.indexOf(textData) > -1;
            });
            setFilteredData(newData);
            setSearch(text);
        } else {
            setFilteredData(masterData);
            setSearch(text);
        }
    }
    
    return(
        <SafeAreaView style={manageCustomersStyle.safeAreaView}>
            <Appbar.Header>
                <Appbar.BackAction onPress={backPage} />
                <Appbar.Content title ="Manage Customers" />         
            </Appbar.Header>
            <View style={manageCustomersStyle.searchBarView}>
                <Icon 
                name="search"
                size={30}
                color="grey"
                style={manageCustomersStyle.searchBarIcon}/>
                <TextInput
                style={manageCustomersStyle.searchBar}
                placeholder={'Search'}
                value={search}
                onChangeText={(text) => searchFilter(text)}/>
            </View>
            <FlatList 
                data={filteredData}
                keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
                renderItem={ItemView}
            />
        </SafeAreaView>
    );
}

export default ManageCustomersScreen;
```

These screenshots shows when i start typing in the `TextInput` the `FlatList` simply disappears.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## General

Typescript is meant for writing typed javascript. Currently, you're just writing javascript in a Typescript file. You're not really using Typescript.

You'd greatly benefit from reading: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes.html

## For this specific problem

I would start by changing this line to actually include type data:

```
const [masterData, setMasterData] = useState([]);
```

Currently, the most strict type Typescript can determine for `masterData` would be `any[]`, which is bad. You want to avoid `any` whenever you can, as it means that Typescript cannot perform any type check for this variable.

For example, if title is an optional string, you could write:

```
const [masterData, setMasterData] = useState<{ title?: string }[]>([]);
```

Or even better, you could define this as a type:

```
interface MasterDataItem {
  title?: string
}
```

And then use it like this:

```
const [masterData, setMasterData] = useState<MasterDataItem[]>([]);
```

Comment: this is runtime problem, and typescript is not for runtime

Comment: Sorry for not responding all this time. Thanks a lot, bro, you really helped me!

Answer (score 1):

On This code you write  `item.name`

```
<Text style={manageCustomersStyle.customerCardInfoName}>{item.name}</Text>
```

but on function `searchFilter` you try compare `item.title`, seems you typo it should `item.name` instead `item.title`